# Can a `<button type="submit">` be used in place of a `f.submit` in a Rails `form_for` form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to standardize all the buttons and button-styled elements in our Rails app with a button component. This means rendering a styled `<button>` element with type `"button"` or type `"submit"`. I'm making use of the `view_component` gem provided by github!

I am hoping to be able to replace all Rails form helper-y elements such as `button_tag`, `submit_tag` and `f.submit` with a button element. I'm pretty new to Rails, and I am not sure if there are things happening under the hood I'm not taking into account. Looking at the Rails [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object), it doesn't seem like there anything special with the `f.submit` form helper element.

Am I missing something? Are there consequences to replacing rails form helper submits with a `button[type='submit']`?

Comment: There's nothing particularly magic about (most) of the ActionView helpers. Ultimately they just generate HTML. As long as you conform to conventions expected by controllers (e.g., the ID names of form field elements), you are free to generate your own HTML.

Comment: You might want to keep using Rails' helpers in case you later decide to use something like  bootstrap_form.

Comment: Why do you want to replace all the helpers?

Answer (score 0):

It would be long way to change stuff, so Better to use css and adjust css to get your requirements.

Just add following in you code to create your own my_submit_button

```
### app/helpers/application_helper.rb ###

module ApplicationHelper

 def my_submit
    # decide what the submit text should be
    text = if @record.new_record?
            "Create #{@record.class}"
          else
            "Update #{@record.class}"
          end

    # build and return the tag string
    my_submit_tag(text)
  end
end
```

further you can read here
[The form_for helper](https://launchschool.com/books/demystifying_rails/read/form_for_helper)